# TableView how to implement cells overlap with custom scroll

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I need to implement vertical and horizontal tables with overlapped cells and custom scrolling.

It should looks like this:

[image]

Table can have many cells (about 1000), so recycling is need too.

Do you know any third party components or may be standart that can helps me. Or i need to write my custom "TableView"?

Comment: So scrolling should start when cells not overlap? What about if you in the middle of long list - how invisible cell must moving?

Comment: Yes scrolling should start when all visible cells are not overlap. Yes this is small hack... Invisible cells must appears from top already extended (not overlapped).

Comment: I think you will have to implement this in your own custom `UIScrollView`. Are you?

Answer (score 4):

What you're describing would be very difficult in a standard `UITableView`, since it requires controlling the layout of individual cells. The good news is that Apple *does* provide an API for specifying the the layout of reusable cells in whatever manner you want; the only wrinkle being that it is for `UICollectionView`s, not `UITableView`s. If you don't need to support older versions of iOS, I would encourage you to watch the WWDC sessions on collection views, and then check out [Schwa's Coverflow project](https://github.com/schwa/Coverflow) for a solid implementation of a similar style layout.